# Correct type for class variable (e.g. fArr = Uint32Array)

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

```
const fArr: Function = Uint32Array;
new fArr(5);
```

the code (above) works fine. But typescript throws a TS2351 error.

"This expression is not constructable. Type 'Function' has no construct signatures".

Please help...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just define a constructor type:

```
type Constructor<T = any> = new (...args: any[]) => T;

const fArr: Constructor = Uint32Array;
new fArr(5);
```